# Jsoup Parsing Empty Tags with no contents

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsoup

I am trying to parse an html page i downloaded using jsoup with jsoup.
I have a code that reads html page and returns html string output, after which i save to a file using bytestream. 
The problem am having is parsing the so called html page i downloaded, to retrieve its title. When i try parsing it all i can get is tags with empty contents like so:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  cores/core/log/DJade_Tmp/tmp__11755159/tmp_yh/tmp_content/998159649.html
 </body>
</html>
```

`Here is the content of the html page`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <link href="/d2/bs/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <title>Java Swing Tutorials</title> 
  <meta content="Java Swing Programming Tutorials - Online Java tutorials provides swing tutorials, swing example and code, swing example programs, definition of java swing, free java swing tutorials. Also read useful java articles and resouces on java and advanced java programming." name="description"> 
  <meta content="java swing, java swing tutorials, swing example java, online swing tutorials, swing example code java, free java code, java tutorials, online java tutorials, free java tutorials" name="keywords"> 
  <link href="/d1/prettify/prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-6980313-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script> 
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script> 
  <script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-0714075272818912",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script> 
  .......
```

I can paste the whole contents of the page cause its too long.
As you can see the title is there and other contents of the page, but am getting empty tags.

**Here is the code i save the page with:**

```
/************ HERE WE DETERMINE TO DOWNLOAD BY JSOUP OR HTTPURLCONNECTION **********/
    if(type.equals("jsd")){
    // HERE WE DOWNLOAD USING JSOUP
    pageStrings=new String[1][Contents.length];
    // Now lets loop to download individual url String
    for(int j=0; j<Urls.length; j++){
        if(Urls[j].toString().indexOf(".pdf")>=0 || Urls[j].toString().indexOf(".xml")>=0){
            pdfList.add(Urls[j].toString());
            //pageStrings[1][j]=Urls[j].toString();
        }
        else{
            String sUrl="";
            Document doc=null;
            Connection con=Jsoup.connect(Urls[j].toString()).timeout(50000).ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true).userAgent(userAgent);
            Connection.Response resp = con.execute();
            // HERE WE CHECK RESPONSE CODE
            if (resp.statusCode() == 200) {
                doc = con.get();
                // Now lets get the text document
                pageStrings[0][j]=doc.html();
                urlList.add(Urls[j].toString());
                //pageStrings[0][j]=Jsoup.connect(Urls[j].toString()).timeout(50000).ignoreHttpErrors(true).userAgent(userAgent).get().html();
            } // End of status check
            else if(resp.statusCode() == 307){
                String sNewUrl = resp.header("Location");
                if (sNewUrl != null && sNewUrl.length() > 7)
                    sUrl = sNewUrl;
                resp = Jsoup.connect(sUrl).timeout(50000).ignoreHttpErrors(true).userAgent(userAgent).execute();
                doc =resp.parse();
                // Now lets get the text document
                pageStrings[0][j]=doc.html();
                urlList.add(Urls[j].toString());
            } // End of status 307 check

        }
    } // End of loop

    // HERE WE CREATE THE META DATA
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pageStrings[0])+"------>"+pageStrings[0].length);
    // Lets compose list to array
    // Now we change data of array
    pdfUrlType=pdfList.toArray(new String[pdfList.size()]); // Composed pdf url type
    xhtmlTypeUrl=urlList.toArray(new String[urlList.size()]); // Compose url type
    xhtmlUrl=new URL[xhtmlTypeUrl.length];
    // now lets loop to turn to url
    for(int o=0; o<xhtmlTypeUrl.length; o++){
        xhtmlUrl[o]=new URL(xhtmlTypeUrl[o]);
    } // End of loop
    // NOW LETS CREATE META
    meta=new MetaWizard(xhtmlUrl, null);

    // NOW LETS SAVE THE RETURN HTML TO TMP
    if(pageStrings[0].length>0){
    downloader=new DjadeTmp(pageStrings[0], "html", "[n]["+meta.metaWriter()+"]");
    FileDatas=downloader.save(null);
    } // End of page string check for html
```

What could be the reason the page is not parsing? any help will be totally appreciated. Am using eclipse to run my project

Comment: I doesn't see any Jsoup query in your code...

Comment: Am not querying, i was just using the title() method to get the title and it seems like jsoup is not able to parse the document and so it creating the empty tags